# Integrate password_compat library

Tags: php, codeigniter, bcrypt

This is not my first time using CodeIgniter or Bcrypt, but it is my first time using a [specific library of Bcrypt with CodeIgniter.](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) I am having issue integrating thee two together.

Lets get to the code :

```
 public function create_user($value) {
        $this -> CI = get_instance(); // Get the CI instance
        $this -> CI -> load -> library('bcrypt'); // Use this to load the library from within the model 

        $hash = $this -> CI -> bcrypt -> password_hash($value[":password"], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 17)); Here is where things get shaky.

        $value[":password"] = $hash; // Here I take the :password placeholder and update the clear text password with the bcrypt pasword

        var_dump($value[":password"]); // This gives me NULL, I assume because I am getting errors with $hash = .......

 ........................................
```

as per manual with Password_compat :

> BCRYPT also allows for you to define a cost parameter in the options
>   array. This allows for you to change the CPU cost of the algorithm:
>
> $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" =>
>   10));

On my front end these are the errors I keep getting :

> Message: Use of undefined constant PASSWORD_BCRYPT - assumed
>   'PASSWORD_BCRYPT'
>
> Message: password_hash() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

I made this into a library itself so I put it into application/librarys folder

**[This is the file](http://pastebin.com/8bnBN6CG)**

any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Are you running php 5.5+? Looks like that constant wasn't added until then, which would also cause the message about param 2 not being what is expected.

Comment: I am running PHP 5.3 with sushin patch

Comment: Ya, the PASSWORD_BCRYPT constant wasn't brought in until 5.5. http://php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php

Comment: I am an absolute idiot. Just wow. I'll answer this question. Sorry for wasting  your time!

Answer (score 0):

Okay [well looking at this file](http://pastebin.com/8bnBN6CG) (which was my old Bcrypt.php file)

You notice I do not have these lines added :

```
if (!defined('PASSWORD_DEFAULT')) {

    define('PASSWORD_BCRYPT', 1);
    define('PASSWORD_DEFAULT', PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

Well the reason I removed them was because I had put the above snippet of code under the Class Bcrpyt { ... line which would cause an error.

Now I put this snippet code :

```
if (!defined('PASSWORD_DEFAULT')) {
        define('PASSWORD_BCRYPT', 1);
        define('PASSWORD_DEFAULT', PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

  Class Bcrypt {
```

This is all I had to do for it to work. Silly me! Now it works :

> string(60)
>   "$2y$17$9qgFDbN3361DAQFilGZySuJ4czachQThuskoSj4DihkxjwGFqTx2e"